# Finding the differentials of a function given the transformations

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

Given the following transformations, find the differentials of the given functions

\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{array}{cl}{r^{\prime}=\frac{r}{\sqrt{\left(1-r^{2} / R^{2}\right)}} e^{-ct / R},} & {t^{\prime}=t+\frac{R}{2 c} \ln \left(1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)} \\ {\theta^{\prime}=\theta,} & {\phi^{\prime}=\phi}\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}

Solving for r and t we find that 
\begin{equation}
r = r^{\prime} \left( \sqrt{1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right) e^{ct/R}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
t=t^{\prime} - \frac{R}{2 c} \ln{ \left(1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)}
\end{equation}
then the differential for $dr$ is as follows,
\begin{gather*}
dr = \frac{\partial r}{\partial r^{\prime}} dr^{\prime} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial t^{\prime}} dt^{\prime} \\
\implies \frac{\partial }{\partial r^{\prime}} \bigg(r^{\prime} \left( \sqrt{1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right) e^{ct/R} \bigg)dr^{\prime} + 0dt^{\prime} \\
\implies \left( \sqrt{1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}}\right) e^{ct/R} dr^{\prime}
\end{gather*}

which I believe is correct, nonetheless, when I attempt to derive the differential for $dt^{\prime}$ I unfortunately don't arrive at the correct differential, i.e. 
\begin{gather*}
dt = \frac{\partial t}{\partial r^{\prime}} dr^{\prime} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial t^{\prime}} dt^{\prime} \\
\implies = \frac{\partial }{\partial r^{\prime}} \bigg( t^{\prime} - \frac{R}{2 c} \ln{ \left(1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)} \bigg)dr^{\prime} + \frac{\partial }{\partial t^{\prime}} \bigg( t^{\prime} - \frac{R}{2 c} \ln{ \left(1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)} \bigg)dt^{\prime} \\
\implies = 0 dr^{\prime} + (1) dt^{\prime}
\end{gather*}
Yet I believe that the correct differential should be something along the lines of 
\begin{equation}
dt = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}} \right)}} dt^{\prime}
\end{equation}

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Should I define the $r^{2}$ inside the natural logarithm in terms of $r^{\prime}$? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You did not successfully solve for $r$ as a function of $r',t'$. Note that your formula for $r$ has $r$ itself on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was able to figure it out, by exactly that.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will be sure to solve for r as a function of $r^{\prime}$ and $t^{\prime}$, by your comment I assume we must make sure that r is specifically on one side and not both in our relation, correct?

Comment: I derived the following relation for $r$ as a function of $r^{\prime}$, rather, I found the relation of $r^{2}$ as follows: $r^{2} = \frac{r^{\prime 2}e^{\frac{2ct}{R}} R^{2}}{(1+R^{2}})$. Would this be the correct relation? Would this imply that $r = \frac{r^{\prime}e^{\frac{ct}{R}} R}{\sqrt{(1+R^{2}}}$?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend finding $dr'$ and $dt'$ in terms of $dr$ and $dt$ and then calculate the inverse matrix.

Comment: I see. Yes I shall try this then